# Remove property from relationship getting error "neobolt.exceptions.NotALeaderError: No write operations are allowed directly on this database"

Tags: neo4j

I have a query to remove property from a node but whenever i try to remove i get the following error
 `neobolt.exceptions.NotALeaderError: No write operations are allowed directly on this database. Writes must pass through the leader. The role of this server is: FOLLOWER`

Here is the query
`` MATCH (n) WHERE n:`BA` and n:`test 2` Remove n.`test 50.title`,n.`test 2.Abc`,n.`test 50.Abc ``

Comment: Which tool are you using to run the query? Neo4j Browser? Cypher shell? Your own program?

Comment: Browser and my program both are giving the same result

Comment: what Neo4j version are you using? it seems like you've deployed a cluster and you're using a URI with the bolt:// scheme to connect to a follower instead of a leader (followers cannot perform write operations like the property removal you're trying to do here). Switching to the neo4j:// scheme should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to execute it with 'write role operation'